# Prove that $\log_34\cdot\log_56\cdot\log_78\cdot\ldots\cdot\log_{79}80 > 2$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, products

The title basically says it all, we've got to prove the inequality without calculating the value of the left side:
$$\prod_{n = 2}^{40}\log_{2n - 1}(2n) > 2$$
aka
$$\log_34\cdot\log_56\cdot\log_78\cdot\ldots\cdot\log_{79}80 > 2$$

Everything I've tried eventually brings be back to where I started... I'm obviously missing the key here and for god's sake I can't think of anything new anymore! :D

Every suggestion is welcome. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
$$
\log_34>\log_45\\
\log_56>\log_67\\
\vdots
$$
So
$$
(\log_34\cdot\log_56\cdots\log_{79}80)^2>\log_34\cdot\log_45\cdots\log_{79}80\cdot\log_{80}81
$$
The right-hand side is equal to $4$. This is easiest to see if you raise $3$ to the power of the right-hand side and use the logarithms one by one until you end up with $81=3^4$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I had actually come to the same expression myself, but then got mislead by not noticing the equal count of factors on both sides... So I threw it away... xD Anyway, thanks a lot again!